# Is it possible to add images to Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to add images to Cognito Forms so that the user makes a selection from three thumbnails?

Answer (score 2):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. We do not have a way to place an image inside of a from to be used as a thumbnail for the selection process. However we are looking into this as a future feature. You can follow the progress of this idea on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/eCd6cqRv).

Answer (score 2):

I am part of the Cognito Forms team. Today we released a new update that includes the ability to add images using our Content fields. You could then create individual Choice fields for each image to allow for selections. You can learn more about adding images in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/29/building-forms/form-field-reference/content-field#add-images).